# Java DLL Function: Connecting to MicroFocus Rumba ehlapi32

Tags: java, c#, swing, winapi, kernel32

I have an issue that I've been trying to solve for months now. I am trying to connect to MicroFocus Rumba using the ehlapi32.dll library in Java. There are not many references online for Java. I have tried loading them using JNA, but i continue receiving a '1' status which means the process given is incorrect. I am not sure if this is an issue of declaring the function correctly or possibly the process. I have manually provided the processID by using windows cmd 'tasklist' and finding my WDDspPag.bin PID.

I have written many VB programs and connect just fine with the following:

```
Declare Function WD_ConnectPS Lib "Ehlapi32.DLL" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal ShortName As String) As Integer
Declare Function WD_CopyPSToString Lib "Ehlapi32.DLL" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal Position As Integer, ByVal Buffer As String, ByVal length As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function WD_CopyStringToPS Lib "Ehlapi32.DLL" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal Position As Integer, ByVal Buffer As String, ByVal length As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function WD_SendKey Lib "Ehlapi32.DLL" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal KeyData As String) As Integer
Declare Function WD_DisconnectPS Lib "Ehlapi32.DLL" (ByVal hInstance As Long) As Integer
```

My issue could be the process, which in VB i declare like this:

```
Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

So I would like to know if my process is being declared correctly? If I can manually enter the process for testing purposes? I suppose i need to "find" the Rumba process, but the below code seems to give me the process which JVM is using?

```
    import com.sun.jna.Library;
    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.Platform;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;


    public class RumbaConnect {


         public interface ehlapi32 extends Library {
             ehlapi32 ehlapi32 = (ehlapi32) Native.loadLibrary(
                    (Platform.isWindows() ? "ehlapi32" : "ehlapi32"), ehlapi32.class);
                public int WD_ConnectPS(long hInstance , String ShortName);
                public int WD_DisconnectPS(long hInstance);
            }
        public static final ehlapi32 ehlapi32 = (ehlapi32) Native.loadLibrary("ehlapi32", ehlapi32.class);   
        public static final Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);



         public static void main(String[] args) {
             int process = 0; 
             int status = 0; 

             process = kernel32.GetCurrentProcessId();
             status = ehlapi32.WD_ConnectPS(process, "a");
            // status = getProcAddress.WD_ConnectPS(5976, "A");
                System.out.println("Your Rumba Status: " + status);

         }
        /*  0  The function was successful  
            1  An incorrect PSID was specified  
            8  No prior call to Start Communication Notification (80) function was called for the PSID  
            9  A system error was encountered  
        */
    }
```

Finally, the expected result should be 'zero,' as provided in the Java comments. Thanks in advance. The libraries load fine, i set the path in Eclipse via Eclipse -> Windows -> Pref -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit Default JRE -> and entered "-Djava.library.path=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Rumba\system" So i don't believe loading the libraries is an issue.

Edit:

Additionally, the VB code above is used in MSAccess and MS Excel, so it could be that there are reference libraries loaded by default and it simply works with a simply declaration of a function. Specifically this:

```
Declare Function WD_ConnectPS Lib "Ehlapi32.DLL" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal ShortName As String) As Integer
```

Only the instance and the Rumba window (in this case "A") is passed, then it returns a status of either '0' which means its active and ready, or some other code (see code comments).

Comment: Of course `GetCurrentProcessId` gives you your current process id, not the id of some other process you might be interested in (how would it know which one you wanted?) This code appears to be redundant: `Platform.isWindows() ? "ehlapi32" : "ehlapi32"`

Comment: Yea, i figured that much.. that is why i entered the PID manually. I could figure out how automate that later, for now I am focused on "connecting" to Rumba via Java. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: No, sorry. What value do you pass to `WD_ConnectPS` in VB? The value returned from `GetCurrentProcessId` there? That wouldn't seem to make sense, but...

Comment: Nope, that's where the ehlapi32 library comes into play. You simply pass the processid + the Rumba letter (in this case "A") and if the Rumba windows is available, it will output a '0.' Otherwise, something else. I'll add this to my question for additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It turns out the hInstance needs to be declared as 'int' and not 'long.' After i continued playing around with the code i finally was able to communicate from Java and send a string. The code is below in case anyone would like it as an example. It is actual working code that connects and sends a string. You are able to add all of the EHLAPI functions with ease with this code below:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;


public class RumbaConnect {


     public interface ehlapi32 extends Library {
         ehlapi32 ehlapi32 = (ehlapi32) Native.loadLibrary(
                (Platform.isWindows() ? "ehlapi32" : "ehlapi32"), ehlapi32.class);
            public int WD_ConnectPS(int hInstance , String ShortName);
            public int WD_SendKey(int hInstance, String KeyData);
        }
    public static final ehlapi32 ehlapi32 = (ehlapi32) Native.loadLibrary("ehlapi32", ehlapi32.class);   
    public static final Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);



     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int process = 0; 
         int status = 0; 
         int intResult = 0; 

         process = kernel32.GetCurrentProcessId();
         status = ehlapi32.WD_ConnectPS(process, "A");
         intResult = ehlapi32.WD_SendKey(process, "MYNAME");
            System.out.println("Your Rumba Status: " + status);

     }
    /*  0  The function was successful  
        1  An incorrect PSID was specified  
        8  No prior call to Start Communication Notification (80) function was called for the PSID  
        9  A system error was encountered  
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier done with C# .NET using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9615/Using-EHLLAPI-in-C as an example. Since C# and Java are very similar you could possibly take a look at that. Additionally you could possibly use the Java .NET libraries to assist in simulating the C# program. An additional, but not a first choice would be to run a shell script using vb to scrape while using Java as the graphical interface. This would work well if the data is of fair size and can be stored from a text file to a vector.